# Change Music.app icon (Big Sur)

Tags: big-sur, icon, customization

does anyone know of a way to replace the Apple Music app icon with a custom .icns file? It seems this disallowed for some system apps (also Messages for example). Thank you in advance for any tips.

Comment: Default **macOS Big Sur** _applications_ are on a _cryptographically signed read-only volume_. While there are steps that can be taken to break the seal and make the volume writable, nonetheless, it is IMO not worth the steps it takes and that it breaks FileVault in the process.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and suggestion.